# Is there an option to display in my labels only the numbers after decimals?

Tags: matlab

I am using the following command in order to show labeled data in my figure:

```
L = strsplit(sprintf('(%.2f,%.2f)\n', L'), '\n');

conf_int_session = strsplit(sprintf('(%d\n,','%d\n)', conf_int_low(:),conf_int_up(:)), '\n');
```

However, The numbers in as produced by `(%.2f,%.2f)` are all between 0 and 1.

Is there an option to display in my labels only the numbers after decimals? i.e. instead of `(0.23,0.57)` I would like to display `(.23,.57)`.

Comment: Replace the string `0.` with `.`: `L = strrep(L, '0.', '.')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
strsplit(sprintf('(.%2.0f,.%2.0f)\n', 100*L'), '\n')
```